# How to remove a value from a map in typescript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I have `myMap: { [key: string]: string[] } = {}` and I want to remove a value for some certain key from `myMap`.

That is delete `value1` from `myMap[Key1]`.

I have done my google search but I failed to find it.

Comment: `.delete(key)` ??

Answer (score 3):

You can either remove both key and value:

```
myMap.delete(key);
```

Or reassign the value to `undefined`:

```
myMap.set(key, undefined);
```

<sub>Do note the first solution comes up with a Google search of `javascript map delete value`</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways:

1. By using `delete` (mutation)

```
delete myMap[Key1]
```

2. By using object destructuring (no mutation), however note that a possibly unwanted variable `_` will be created.

```
const {[Key1]: _, ...updatedMyMap} = myMap
```

Comment: `delete` is used to delete the property of an object not an object value from the map. Or am i missing something here?